# Convert Sencha Touch-based app source code into native objective C code

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, sencha-touch, hybrid-mobile-app

I have already created an application using **Sencha Touch** ,But now for some of the reasons i want to convert it into **native application with native source code(objective C) and interfaces(xib)**.I searched for a solution but still i didn't find a better solution.

I want to know is there a way to convert **Sencha Touch** project into native Xcode project with Objective C.

Thank You...

Comment: no, not possible. you need to completely recode it. javascript and objective c are different languages, you can't just convert from one to another.

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/getting-started-with-sencha-touch-2-build-a-weather-utility-app-part-3/

Or this other one:

http://frightanic.com/software-development/sencha-touch-native-packaging-for-ios-done-right/

Comment: I just checked ur answer,but it didn't answer my question,Currently i can open the app and run its using xCode,but source codes are included in a folder called "www" and it contains javascript code,But what i want is Source code should be in **Objective C** like in native application.which means i want to convert the source code.
Anyways Thanks for ur help.